# Collapse the nav bar automatically after clicking on an item

Tags: angular, aspnetboilerplate, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to automatically collapse the menu bar after a link is clicked. I have used the code below but it loads the whole page and I don't want it to reload the page.

```html
<div>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="'/app/home'">
        <i class="fa fa-cubes"></i> Website
    </a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <ng-template ngFor let-menuItem [ngForOf]="mainMenuItems" let-mainMenuItemIndex="index">
            <li *ngIf="showMenuItem(menuItem)" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" [routerLink]="[menuItem.route]">
                    <i class="{{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
                    <span class="title hidden-sm">{{l(menuItem.name)}}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ng-template>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you reproduce same state and provide a live demo.